# MySQL: Is WHERE IN clause case sensitive?

Tags: mysql

I was just wondering if the `IN` clause in MySQL is case sensitive or not when it comes to string values. For example below. Will it display all the data regardless if it is on upper case or not?

```js
SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column2 IN ('sample1','Sample2','sampLe3')
```

Comment: Why are you not checking yourself?

Comment: Mark, really, like 5 minutes to put this question together !

Comment: @mark its case insensitive

Comment: Look here : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15250/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is actually based on your db/table/column collation. If your collation is case-sensitive, the operator will also behave case-sensitively.

Comment: Thanks dude. I search my default Collation and it says that by default it is case insensitive.